# Borrar filas de un datagridview

Tags: c#

Hola intento borrar filas con el siguiente código pero me sale un error. He probado de todo pero no consigo saber porque no me deja borrar las filas del data gridview.

```
private void button_BorrarUv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridViewUvCnf.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
    {
         dataGridViewUvCnf.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewUvCnf.CurrentRow.Index);
    }
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error cuando ejecuto esto:

> InvalidOperationException: No se puede eliminar filas mediante programación a menos que DataGridView esté enlazado a datos con IBindingList que admita la notificación de cambios y permita la eliminación.

El codigo del Desginer es el siguiente

```
this.button_BorrarUv.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_BorrarUv_Click);
```

Por que ocurre este error? He probado de cambiar el EventArgs por DataGridViewCellEventArgs pero no me deja cambiarlo me sale un error en el designer. No consigo saber que significa un IBiningList. En las propiedades del datagridview he puesto que habilite la edición y habilite eliminar filas pero sigue sin funcionar.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `DataGridView` tiene básicamente dos modos de funcionamiento:

- Uno en el que le añades la información añadiendo filas a la colección `Rows` y rellenando esta con datos.

En este caso las modificaciones las realizas directamente en las celdas, y añades y eliminas filas directamente de la colección `Rows`

- Otro en el que la información la toma de una fuente de datos externa enlazada al control a través de la propiedad `DataSource`.

En este caso las modificaciones deberían realizarse en el origen de datos externo. Es decir si se quiere eliminar un registro debería eliminarse éste del origen de datos e indicar al `DataGridView` que refresque la información a partir del origen de datos.

El error que te aparece indica que estás utilizando el `DataGridView` para mostrar la información de una fuente de datos externa y que por lo tanto no puedes eliminar filas directamente de la colección `Rows`.

Comment: De acuerdo entonces borraré el dato de mi origen de datos y refrescare el datagridview para ver los cambios. Para hacer el refresco es el metodo datagridview.Refresh imagino

Comment: Sí, con llamar al método `Refresh` te debería bastar.

Comment: De acuerdo ya me sale gracias!

Comment: @Xim123 Si te ha funcionado, considera aceptar la respuesta de Asier para que otros con tu mismo problema puedan saber que su solucion funciona