# Como agregar Filas a una DataGridView que ya este enlazada a datos en C#

Tags: c#

previamente he creado un DataGridView.DataSource= "una consulta"

y luego deseo agregarle otra fila a esa desde otra consulta`

```
if (result== DialogResult.OK)
{
     DataTable tb1 = ConexionBD.Data("SELECT Id, Nombre, Cantidad as Disponibilidad, 1 Cantidad, Precio FROM Producto WHERE Id = '"+captura[0]+"'");

     if (tb1.Rows.Count == 0)
     {
           MessageBox.Show("No se encuentra ningun producto con ese Codigo");
     }
     else
     {
           if (tablaVenta.Rows.Count==0)
           {
                tablaVenta.DataSource = tb1;
           }
           else
           {
                tablaVenta.Rows.Add(tb1.Rows[0][0], tb1.Rows[0][1], tb1.Rows[0][2], tb1.Rows[0][3], tb1.Rows[0][4]);
           }
     }
}
else
{
     cxProduc.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Debes añadir las filas al DataSource.

Comment: Como te comenta @Pikoh las modificaciones deberías realizarlas en el DataSource. Échale un vistazo a esta otra respuesta, creo que te puede ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139819/borrar-filas-de-un-datagridview/139824#139824

Comment: De hecho @AsierVillanueva, esta se puede considerar un duplicado de la pregunta que enlazas.No la voy a votar como duplicado porque en aquella habla de eliminar y en esta de añadir, pero básicamente es lo mismo

Comment: Como te comentan todos la idea que el origen de datos (datasource) tenga los datos para bindear por eso debes agregar alli. Cuando dices "agregarle otra fila a esa desde otra consulta..." cual es la idea? puedes explayarte mas en la descripcion o sea quieres de otra tabla, con otro identificador (Id en tu ejemplo)? si es esto ultimo deberias "guardar" todos los IDENTIFICADORES que deseas "cargar" y luego armar un query SQL acorde a esta solicitud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, segun tu codigo, lo que deseas hacer es agregar datos a tu `DataGridView` por el id, basicamente la consulta es la mima, no entiendo lo de "**1 Cantidad**"  en tu consulta, pero creo que te traes 5 datos en ella.

Segun lo que describo lo unico que debes hacer es reemplazar la siguiente linea codigo:

> tablaVenta.Rows.Add(tb1.Rows[0][0], tb1.Rows[0][1], tb1.Rows[0][2], tb1.Rows[0][3], tb1.Rows[0][4]);

Por:

```
DataRow row = tb1.Rows[0];
string[] aux = new string[] { row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString() };
tablaVenta.Rows.Insert(int.Parse(tablaVenta.Size.ToString()),aux);
```

Es en la ultima linea(`tablaVenta.Rows.Insert(int.Parse(tablaVenta.Size.ToString()),aux);`) donde insertamos una nueva fila al final de nuestro datagrid, en caso de que quieras que se inserte al inicio de la lista lo cambias por: `tablaVenta.Rows.Insert(0,aux);`.

Espero haber acertado.

Comment: "1 Cantidad" es un campo que quiero qe traiga adicional y que venga predertminado con el valor de 1

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo como esto:

```
//.......
//.......

if (tablaVenta.Rows.Count==0)
{
    tablaVenta.DataSource = tb1;
}
else
{
    //Crear un DataTable con las Columnas del DataGriview
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    datatable = tablaVenta.DataSource as DataTable;

    //Agregar las Filas al DataRow
    DataRow datarow;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        datarow = datatable.NewRow();
        datarow[i].ToString();
        datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
     }
}
```

> Me disculpo si hay algún error, estoy desde el móvil y no he probado la solución.

Comment: y en que momento de las pasaria al DataGridView?

Comment: @srJJ al hacer esto `datatable = tablaVenta.DataSource as DataTable;` estas creando un datatable con los datos que ya tiene tu `DataGridView` por lo tanto ya cuando termine el ciclo se reflejarán los cambios en el inmediatamente si ya lo tenias enlazado antes de hacer esta parte.

Comment: bueno, gracias voy a verlo, aunque algo similar ya habia intentado sin frutos

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtr = new DataTable();
        //Tengo un datagridview donde el usuario elige a una persona y 
        //la consulta se añade al mismo
        frmBuscaPersonal ofb = new frmBuscaPersonal();
        ofb.ShowDialog();
        if (ofb.rId_Trabajador > 0)
        {
            oReportes.pIdTrabajador = ofb.rId_Trabajador;
            dtr = oReportes.Deposito_Banco_Individual();
            //verificamos si el datagridview tiene registros
            if (dgvListaTrabajadores.RowCount == 0)
            {
                dgvListaTrabajadores.DataSource = dtr;
            }
            else //si tiene algun registro añadimos 
            {
                dt = dgvListaTrabajadores.DataSource as DataTable;

                //Agregar las Filas al DataRow
                DataRow datarow;
                datarow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < dtr.Columns.Count; i++)
                {                        
                    datarow[i] = dtr.Rows[0][i].ToString();                        
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(datarow);
                dgvListaTrabajadores.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```