# No puedo agregar filas a un datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Tengo un problema al agregar nuevas filas a un datagrid me marca el siguiente error: **"No se pueden agregar filas mediante programación a la colección de filas de DataGridView cuando el control está enlazado a datos"**

El código que utilizo para agregar filas es este:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prodcod.Text, articulo.Text, talla.Text, manga.Text, unidad.Text, cantidad.Text, preciou.Text, subtotal.Text, descuento.Text, total.Text);
```

Y el que uso para rellenar el datagridview es este:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=10.1.1.1\novtosa; user=usr; password=Nov; Initial Catalog=menu;");
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PRODCOD, ARTICULO, MANGA, TALLA, UNIDAD, CANTIDAD, PRECIOUNIT, SUBTOTAL, PORCEN_DESCUENTO, TOTAL, NUM_REMISION from borradorlineas where NUM_REMISION like @idd", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", Convert.ToString(Buscarborrador.Borradorseleccionado.Numremision));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "PRODCOD";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ARTICULO";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "MANGA";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "TALLA";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "UNIDAD";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "CANTIDAD";
dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "PRECIOUNIT";
dataGridView1.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "SUBTOTAL";
dataGridView1.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "PORCEN_DESCUENTO";
dataGridView1.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "TOTAL";
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
cn.Close();
```

Como puedo agregar nuevas filas a ese datagridview?

Comment: Debes añadir las filas al DataTable del DataSet y no al grid directamente

Comment: [Como agregar Filas a una DataGridView que ya este enlazada a datos en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/143702/69447) Aquí hay respuesta a esa pregunta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el datagrid no siempre se rellena con la consulta sql, aún que no esté enlazado a datos el datagrid podre agregar filas nuevas?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez me puede ayudar un poco más a como agregarle valores de textboxes al insert del post que me comentó?

Comment: Como te estan diciendo los compañeros, en el momento que vinculas el DataTable con el Datasource, lo que debes modificar es el DataTable asociado, no el DataGridView. En caso de que la consulta no devuelva datos, tu DateTable estará inicializado pero sin ningún registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de realizar la asignación `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Debe asignar los datos al `DataTable`, no directamente al `DatagridView`, algo como esto:

```
//Agregar las Filas al DataRow y asignar el valor correspondiente. 
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

DataRow datarow; 
datarow = dt2.NewRow(); //Con esto le indica que es una nueva fila.

datarow["PRODCOD"] =  prodcod.Text;
datarow["ARTICULO"] = articulo.Text;
datarow["MANGA"]= manga.Text;
datarow["TALLA"] = talla.Text;
datarow["UNIDAD"] = unidad.Text;
datarow["CANTIDAD"] = cantidad.Text;
datarow["PRECIOUNIT"] = preciou.Text;
datarow["SUBTOTAL"] = subtotal.Text;
datarow["PORCEN_DESCUENTO"] = descuento.Text;
datarow["TOTAL"] = total.Text;

//Esto se encargará de agregar la fila.
dt2.Rows.Add(datarow);
```

Que es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
DataTable dt = dataGridView1.Source as DataTable;
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { ... });
```

Comment: Perfecto, probaré a ver que tal amigo, Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @p0ncho14 pruebe y cualquier cosa, vuelva por aqui con sus dudas.

Comment: Cuando lo hago como me indico me aparece este error: System.ArgumentException: 'La columna 'PRODCOD' no pertenece a la tabla .' al querer agregar una fila

Comment: @p0ncho14 he actualizado mi respuesta, revise, la modificación, cree un nuevo `DataTable` con las columnas del `DataGridView` si se fija dice `dt2`, revise.

Comment: Ya me funciono! muchas gracias amigo!!! una duda mas si no es mucha molestia como puedo limpiar ese grid tenia: dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); pero me sale este error: System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede borrar esta lista.' :c

Comment: @p0ncho14 Pruebe con `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;`  `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();`
`dataGridView1.Refresh();` eso debería funcionarle

Comment: Funciona amigo gracias! pero le tengo que dar 2 veces al botón limpiar no entiendo por que :/

Comment: @p0ncho14 hay que ver como tiene su botón pero para eso ya debe formular una nueva pregunta en otro post con ese problema especifico y así poder ayudarle